# check if dll is an implementation of pkcs11 version 2.20

Tags: pkcs#11

I want to check that a dll is an implementation of pkcs11 version 2.20 or other version. So I find what are difference between pkcs11 version 2.20 and others (specialy version 2.30). Could you give me some suggest?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/)

> **Version 2.30** This is the draft of the v2.30 version of the standard. The RSA PKCS#11 development process did not move this beyond
>   draft despite the 30 day public final draft review ending 28-Oct-2009.
>   Many vendors have adopted various portions of the draft version.
>
> This version is the basis of the v2.40 OASIS standard version.
>
> **Version 2.20** Published 28 June 2004 this is the most widely used version of the PKCS#11 standard. Most supporting vendors have versions
>   with various vendor-specific extensions based on v2.20.

And regarding the version, you can use the **CK_VERSION** to find out the PKCS#11 Implementation version, more [here].